# Orientation from device fails if VC loads when device is flat Swift

Tags: ios, swift, device-orientation

I'm implementing a barcode scanner for the first time and I'm having a behaviour I don't understand with `AVCaptureDevice` rotation following `Device.rotation`.  I have `productsVC` that goes to `scannerVC` via show segue, than from `scannerVc` it goes to `productDetailsVC` via segue to display the scanned product. I also get back from `productDetailsVC` to `scanerVC` via `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` in a `cancel` button. When I get to `scannerVc` from either view controller if the iPad is laying flat it doesn't rotate `AVCaptureConnection` accordingly to the main view so I get a 90 degrees offset. I tried doing the checking and reorienting both in `viewDidLayout` and `viewWillLayout`but with same results. When they get called, as I'm printing orientation in them, if the iPad is standing than is correct printing `3`, if it's flat than orientation is wrong printing `5` .
Why is not reading orientation as main view instead does? Should I get orientation from main view instead that from `Device`?

This is how I check and apply device device orientation:

```
private func updatePreviewLayer(layer: AVCaptureConnection, orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation) {

        layer.videoOrientation = orientation

        videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.scanView.bounds

    }


    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
            if let connection =  self.videoPreviewLayer?.connection  {

                let currentDevice: UIDevice = UIDevice.current

                let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = currentDevice.orientation

                let previewLayerConnection : AVCaptureConnection = connection

                if (previewLayerConnection.isVideoOrientationSupported) {
                    print("orientation is: \(orientation.rawValue.description)")

                    switch (orientation) {
                    case .portrait: updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .portrait)

                        break

                    case .landscapeRight: updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .landscapeLeft)

                        break

                    case .landscapeLeft: updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .landscapeRight)

                        break

                    case .portraitUpsideDown: updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .portraitUpsideDown)

                        break

                    default: updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .portrait)

                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and this is the function to create the scanner ( I'm testing on an iPad 3 with iOS 9.3.5 so it's a little long function):

```
func setupScanner() {
        if #available(iOS 10.2, *) {
            // Get the back-facing camera for capturing videos
            let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)

            guard let captureDevice = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first else {
                print("Failed to get the camera device")
                return
            }

            do {
                // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

                // Set the input device on the capture session.
                captureSession.addInput(input)

                // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
                let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
                captureSession.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

                // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
                captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
                //            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]
                captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

                // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
                videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                videoPreviewLayer?.frame = scanView.layer.bounds

                scanView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
                // Start video capture.
                captureSession.startRunning()

                // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
                qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

                if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
                    qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                    qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                    scanView.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
                    scanView.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
                }



            } catch {
                // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
                print(error)
                return
            }
        } else if #available(iOS 9.3, *) {

            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video
            // as the media type parameter.
            let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
            do {
                // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)

                // Initialize the captureSession object.
                captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
                // Set the input device on the capture session.
                captureSession?.addInput(input)

                // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
                let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
                captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

                // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
                captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

                // Detect all the supported bar code
                captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

                // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
                videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                videoPreviewLayer?.frame = scanView.layer.bounds
                scanView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
                // Start video capture
                captureSession.startRunning()
                // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
                qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

                if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
                    qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                    qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                    scanView.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
                    scanView.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
                }

            } catch {
                // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying various ways using callbacks I figured out that reading `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation` was the only solution to get it right even when iPad is flat.
The working function is:

```
func readOrientation() {
        let connection =  self.videoPreviewLayer?.connection
        let previewLayerConnection : AVCaptureConnection = connection!
        switch (UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation) {
        case .portrait: self.updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .portrait)

            break

        case .landscapeRight: self.updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .landscapeRight)

            break

        case .landscapeLeft: self.updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .landscapeLeft)

            break

        case .portraitUpsideDown: self.updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .portraitUpsideDown)

            break

        default:

            break
        }
    }
```